# iOS app freeze when delete entity with Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord framework to “clean up” Core Data code. When the app launch or resume from background, the program will try to clean up some data with the following code:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
          NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-259200]; 

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NGCOwner MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"updatedTime" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"updatedTime < %@", date]];

    NSArray *results = [NGCOwner executeFetchRequest:request inContext:localContext];

    NSInteger count = MAX(0,[results count]-100); //do not delete the lastest 100 results

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NGCOwner *owner = [results objectAtIndex:i];
        if([userId isEqualToString:owner.userId]){
            continue;
        }
        [localContext deleteObject:owner];
    }
}];
```

The entity "NGCOwner" has 17 relationships and set the delete rule to Cascade. When the program delete the NGCOwner entity (approx. 170 NGCOwner), it makes the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator busy and freeze the app.

Can I force NSPersistentStoreCoordinator not to execute in main thread?

[image]

After enable core data log, I found the parent context spend most of the time to prefetch the relationship data (Is this normal?).

Comment: Show the logs you get on saving - I see `Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7feb1249fe90): MagicalRecord Root Saving Context> on a background thread`, which isn't blocking the main thread.

Comment: It seems there is a deadlock between the save queue and the PersistentStoreCoordinator. The app freeze for 2 mins and resume.

Comment: @PrimaryChicken did you find solution for that freeze.

Comment: @user1068810 Cause there are too many records and relationships for my table (approx. 2 million records). Instead of deleting the records I created a new database and clone all necessary data to the new database.